# How to store multidimensional data

Tags: r, database

Please consider the following situation:

- I measure values every hour (**time**) (campaign from few month to ~10 years)
- off several **species** (1 to 10)
- with several **instruments** (1 to 5)
- on several measurement **sites** (~70)
- and each site has several **sampling levels** (1 to 5)
- and each value has a **flag** indicating if it is valid or not

I am looking for the fastest and simplest way to store these data, considering the fact that the database/files/whatever should be readable and writeable with R.

Note that:

- Some experiments consist of measuring for a very long time few species, for a single instrument and sampling level,
- Some experiments consist of comparing the same few-months timeframe for a lot of sites (~70)
- Some sites have many sampling levels and/or instruments (which will be compared)
- The storage system must be readable (and if possible writeable) in parallel

What I tried so far:

- MySQL data base, with 1 table per site/species, each table containing the folowing columns: time, sampling level, instrument, value and flag. Of course, as the number of site is growing, the number of table is also growing. And comparing sites is painfull, as it requires a lot of requests. Moreover, sampling level and instrument are repeated a lot of time within the table, this inefficiently occupies space.
- NetCDF files: interesting for their ability to store multi-dimensional data, they good to store a set of data but are not practical to use for daily modification and not very "scalable".
- Druid, a Multidimentional database management system, originally "business intelligence"-oriented. The principle is good, but it is much to heavy and slow for my application.

Thus, I am looking for a system which:

1. Take more or less the same time to retrieve

   - 100 hours of data of 1 site, 1 species, 1 instrument, 1 sampling level, or
   - 10 hours of  data of 10 sites, 1 species, 1 instrument, 1 sampling level, or
   - 10 hours of  data of 1 site, 2 species, 1 instrument, 5 sampling levels, or
   - etc.
2. Allows parallel R/W
3. Minimize the time to write in and read from the database
4. Minimize used disk space
5. Allows easy addition of a new site, or instrument, or species, etc.
6. Works with R

A good system would be a kind of hypercube which allows complex request on all dimensions...

Comment: How many samples/units do you expect?

Comment: Not use to understand what you mean by sample/unit. I wrote the approximate length of each "dimension" in the first list of my post. For example, for the moment I have 1 to 5 instruments per site (depending on the site), some site have 1 instrument measuring 2 species for 10 years (10*365*24=87600 hourly values per species), on other sites I have 5 instruments measuring the same species for 3 months, etc. It is quite variable.

Answer (score 2):

A relational database with a multi-column primary key (or candidate key) is well suited to store this kind of multi-dimensional data.  From your description, it seems that the appropriate primary key would be `time`, `species`, `instrument`, `site`, and `sampling_level`.  The `flag` appears to be an attribute of the value, not a key.  This table should have indexes for all the columns that you will use to select data for retrieval.  You may want additional tables to store descriptions or other attributes of the species, instruments, and sites.  The main data table would have foreign keys into each of these.

Comment: Thanks. The idea is worth trying, but I would like to avoid the waste of disk space implied by the thousands of repetitions of the values in the `time`, `species`, `instrument`, `site`, and `sampling_level` columns. And it does not allow parallel R/W. The others criteria are OK, though!

Comment: Encoding the `species`, `instrument`, `site`, and `sampling_level` values as single-character codes (or more as needed) will minimize storage space.  Lookup tables can provide the full definitions of these.  Memory space in R may be more of an issue than disk space for the database, and compact encodings will help there too.